# Using wp_set_auth_cookie for custom user account system

Tags: cookies

I've built a custom user account system using a custom post type. I was wondering whether it is safe to use the built-in function `wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, $remember, $secure)` Wordpress uses for the built-in user system. For `$user_id` I figured I could use the post id. But wouldn't this clash with the existing system? Is there a nifty trick to keep the default user cookies from clashing with the custom user cookies or shouldn't I use this function at all?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you building a seperate user system in the first place? The wordpress builtin system is pretty flexible.

In theory all the login functions like wp_set_auth_cookie(), wp_generate_auth_cookie(), wp_parse_auth_cookie() etc. are all [pluggable functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions). Which means you can replace them with your own custom functions.

But to be realistic, it will be a lot of work to get this working as you won't be able to use the default `wp_set_auth_cookie()` as long as you replace all login functions, or sync your virtual userbase with the real `wp_users` table.

The default function will not set a valid login cookie unless it finds that `$user_id` is a real wordpress user.

**I think your best options are:**

- Rewrite your login system to use real users instead of your CPT and
  store your custom stuff in user_meta.
- Sync your CPT users with real users (create a real user for each post of your CPT).
- Build your own login system, leave it totally seperate from wordpress users and create the auth_cookies your self.